# How to change content of a tab using $stateProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a view which looks like:

```
<h2>Data Package Management</h2>

<div class="row push-down-md">
    <tabs data="tabData" type="tabs"></tabs>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <tabset>
            <tab heading="Create">
                <div>
                    Create Package
                </div>
            </tab>
            <tab heading="Import"  ui-sref="app.maintenance.portability.import">
                <a ui-sref="app.maintenance.portability.import">Hello</a>
                <div ui-view></div>
            </tab>
        </tabset>
    </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see that when I click on import, it opens the route 'app.maintenance.portability.import' in a new URL. However, I want the contents of that state to load in the `<Div>` below the tab rather than opening it in another window. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this issue with use of ng-include:

```
div class="row push-down-md" >
    <tabs data="tabData" type="tabs"></tabs>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <tabset>
            <tab heading="Export" >
                <div ng-include src= "currentExportDiv"></div>
            </tab>
            <tab heading="Import"  >
                <div ng-include src= "currentImportDiv"></div>       
            </tab>
        </tabset>

    </div>
```

Where both currentImportDiv and currentExportDiv are saperate(or  it can be part of same html) html files. and they render and load on the screen click